Is it possible to NOT override a bean marked as @ConditionalOnMissingBean?
I have a Spring bean defined as such. This is in an external library and cannot be changed. It is also not practical to redefine this bean definition in my project's configuration:
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Service defaultService(Object dependency) {
  return new DefaultService(dependency);
}

I have another bean in the same deployable that has some special behavior that I want to use in certain places while keeping the default definition:
@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
public Service specialCaseService(Object customDependency) {
   return new DefaultService(customDependency);
}

However, since defaultService is marked with ConditionalOnMissingBean, it is not created because the specialCaseService bean exists.
I can just pass a non Spring managed instance to all the beans that need it, but I'm curious if it's possible to register a bean that is not an autowire candidate and won't override the default bean definition.

It's a bit hacky but you could use a wrapper, eg AtomicReference
@Bean
public AtomicReference<Service> specialCaseService(Object customDependency) {
   return new AtomicReference<>(new DefaultService(customDependency));
}

Then
@Inject AtomicReference<Service> serviceRef;
...
serviceRef.get().doStuff();

